# How to animate eye texture (move pupils)

Tags: animation, texturing, materials, modifiers, uv

I have a character model with flat eyes that use a single texture. Is there a way to make the pupils move in an animation. I've tried rigging but that only works with spheres and uv project messes up the uv map.

Comment: Does https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149719/2d-face-animation-on-3d-model-transparent-texture/149722#149722 help? Basically use a separate UV for the eyes and layer them over the base texture to avoid warping the rest of the texture.

Comment: Use the UV Warp modifier as explained here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195493/need-some-help-for-an-experiment-eye-animation